# Bibtex error " I couldn't open file name `Texsaves/References.bib.aux' "

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, errors, cross-referencing, auxiliary-files

I have a problem with bibtex... When I try to run the bibtex File, I incur in the following error.

```
 I couldn't open file name `Texsaves/References.bib.aux'
```

This is my main file, I tried both with .bib and without it in the argument...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}


\nocite{biglaiser2016value}
\bibliographystyle{acm}
\bibliography{References}
\end{document}
```

My preferences for bibtex in the command section of Texmaker are the following,

```
bibtex "Texsaves/%".bib
```

I don't know what to do. I'm using Mac. I've used bibtex 3 times, I just had problems. I tried using `References.bib` in the main (the past times, it worked out), but nothing happens, and I need to fix the problem.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: by default the aux file would be in the current directory not a `build` directory  and if your document is called `doc.tex` you would run `bibtex doc` you also presumably want `/` not `\ ` on a mac if you do need a directory path

Comment: David, I have absolutely no idea what a build directory is.

What should I do? In layman's terms...

Comment: you appear to be calling the command `bibtex build\References`   on a mac it should be `bibtex build/References` if you have a folder `build` that contains `References.aux` but by default latex would not use such a folder and `References.aux` would be in the current directory (assuming your document is `References.tex`) in which case you simply need `bibtex References`

Comment: I changed the command in the preference folder to ```bibtex "build/%".aux ```

Nothing happens though! My current document is not ```Reference.tex ```, Reference.bib is the bibtex file  Should I call it ```Reference.aux``` ???

What is a build folder?

Comment: it's just a name. have you configured tex to write its aux file to a folder called build ? if not then you should not tell bibtex to look there.

Comment: "as suggested elsewhere" -- *where*, please?! This is a prescription for pure disaster.

Comment: Don't call BibTeX on your `.bib` file. BibTeX is called on the `.aux` file of your main `.tex` document. In your editor make sure your main `.tex` file is in focus when you press any compilation buttons.

Comment: "Elsewhere" = Here on Tex.Stack Exchange!!!!


Ok, let's do this again, as it looks like no one is understanding what is going on, and I need a solution.

I'm editing the question with my current settings, so that you can understand better

Comment: @moewe tried to call it from the main, from the bib file, from the kitchen, from the toilet, and I always incur in the same error...

Comment: Well `bibtex "Texsaves/%".bib` is *definitely* wrong: BibTeX is called on the main `.aux` and not on the `.bib`. The error message suggests you are running BibTeX on the `.bib` file: ` I couldn't open file name `Texsaves/References.bib.aux'` (at least if you `.tex` file is not also called `References.tex`). Not knowing your folder set-up I can't tell if the `Texsaves/` subfolder is needed. Is there an `.aux` file in `Texsaves`? (You did run LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX, right? BibTeX can only work after a successful LaTeX run: It needs to find the `.aux`.)

Comment: I didn't understand how, but I solved it. I used `"bibtex"%`option in the preferences, then I don't understand what happened